# Can tcolorbox be integrated with ntheorem?

Tags: tcolorbox, ntheorem

Can tcolorbox be integrated with ntheorem? I.e. with the command `\newtcbtheorem` it does not seem ntheorem recongizes this so that you can put endmarks and include in list of theorems.

Answer (score 3):

Section **Using other theorem environments with tcolorbox** from `tcolorbox` documentation explains how to customize `amsthm` theorems with `tcolorbox`. I've adapted the example there to be used with `ntheorem` and it seems to work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[standard, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\tcolorboxenvironment{lem}{
    enhanced jigsaw, colframe=cyan, interior hidden, breakable, before skip=10pt, after skip=10pt}
    
\tcolorboxenvironment{proof}{
    blanker, breakable, left=5mm, before skip=10pt, after skip=10pt,
    borderline west={1mm}{0pt}{red}}
    
\begin{document}

\listtheorems{lem, proof}

    \begin{lem}[My lema]
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{lem}
    
    \begin{proof}
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]